# How to configure port for a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server, port

How do I configure the TCP/IP port listened on by a Spring Boot application, so it does not use the default port of 8080.

Comment: If someone interested, here is shown how to have multiple ports - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357135/configure-spring-boot-with-two-ports

Comment: if you use "yml" file for configuration then you can use this 
server:
  port: 8081
Also annotate you main class as "@SpringBootApplication"  and remove 
@ EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: your project [application.properties] for add the                               
server.port=8080

Comment: set `server.port=8080` in application properties. this configuration is in `ServerProperties.class` class under `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web`.

Answer (score 1575, accepted):

As [said in docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port) either set `server.port` as system property using command line option to jvm `-Dserver.port=8090` or add `application.properties` in `/src/main/resources/` with

```
server.port=8090
```

For a random port use:

```
server.port=0
```

Similarly add `application.yml` in `/src/main/resources/` with:

```
server:
  port: 8090
```

Comment: When random port is used, port info can get with `@Value("${local.server.port}")`

Comment: Actually command line option is --server.port=8090 not -Dserver.port=8090. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-use-short-command-line-arguments

Comment: As a compliment to this answer: According to the [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) there are other paths you can put `application.properties` on. In my case that helped a lot.

Comment: -Dserver.port=XXXX did not work for me. I used OS environment variable mode: 
`$ SERVER_PORT=8090 java -jar <path/to/my/jar>`

Comment: It is also worth noting that once you so this it will only matter locally. Once you deploy this application on a server `server.port = 8080 will be ignored.

Comment: `java -jar <my.jar> --server.port=8090` works in spring 1.4.0

Comment: Both (1) `java -Dserver.port=XXXX -jar <path/to/my/jar>` and (2) `java -jar <path/to/my/jar> --server.port=YYYY` works. The first command defines `server.port` system property, and the second command pass the property through the command line arguments (`String... args` in the `main` method). Moreover, if you run with `java -Dserver.port=XXXX -jar <path/to/my/jar> --server.port=YYYY`, `YYYY` takes precedence over `XXXX`, this is why Spring Boot Externalized Configuration is so charming.

Comment: Many ways to change port on Spring Boot tomcat http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-change-tomcat-port-command-line.html

Comment: src/resources/application.properties 

server.port=8080
or

Comment: You can set the server.port property in many different ways. Look at the configuration-documentation for spring boot and find the solution that suits you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: In case you prefer maven, do this  `mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=8888`

Comment: application.yaml can also be used instead of properties.

Comment: -Dserver.port did not work but --server.port worked. Also it should be passed to java -jar command and not mvn. So for example after building the projekt using mvn you execute java -jar artifact.jar --server.port=9099 to run the server on another to port

Comment: This does not work

Comment: There is nice explanation of  ways to change port of spring boot  https://www.javavogue.com/2019/02/how-to-change-the-default-port-in-spring-boot/

Comment: Also you can set the management port to expose the actuator on different port

Comment: I had to rebuild the jar to get this to work, by the way

Answer (score 272):

There are two main ways to change the port in the Embedded Tomcat in a Spring Boot Application.

**Modify application.properties**

First you can try the application.properties file in the /resources folder:

```
server.port = 8090
```

[image: application.properties file]

**Modify a VM option**

The second way, if you want to avoid modifying any files and checking in something that you only need on your local, you can use a vm arg:

*Go to Run -> Edit Configurations -> VM options*

```
-Dserver.port=8090
```

[image: Change port with a vm arg]

Additionally, if you need more information you can view the following blog post here:  [Changing the port on a Spring Boot Application](http://codedevstuff.blogspot.com/2015/05/change-port-on-spring-boot-application.html)

Comment: In STS 4 it is at run -> run configurations -> main, then scroll down to Table with Parameter Name and Value

Answer (score 213):

Since Spring Boot provides [various configuration externalization mechanism](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) (through various `PropertySource` implementations and/or processors wired into `Environment` object in order), you can set any property **outside** of your jar archive through following methods:

1. Pass property through command line argument as **application argument**

   ```bash
   java -jar <path/to/my/jar> --server.port=7788
   ```
2. From property in `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` (Spring Boot 1.3.0+)

   - Define environment variable in U*IX shell:

     ```bash
     SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"server.port":7788}' java -jar <path/to/my/jar>
     ```
   - By using Java system property:

     ```bash
     java -Dspring.application.json='{"server.port":7788}' -jar <path/to/my/jar>
     ```
   - Pass through command line argument:

     ```bash
     java -jar <path/to/my/jar> --spring.application.json='{"server.port":7788}'
     ```
3. Define **JVM system property**

   ```bash
   java -Dserver.port=7788 -jar <path/to/my/jar>
   ```
4. Define **OS environment variable**

   - U*IX Shell

     ```bash
     SERVER_PORT=7788 java -jar <path/to/my/jar>
     ```
   - Windows

     ```vb
     SET SERVER_PORT=7788
     java -jar <path/to/my/jar>
     ```
5. Place property in `./config/application.properties` **configuration file**

   ```pl
   server.port=7788
   ```

   and run:

   ```bash
    java -jar <path/to/my/jar>
   ```
6. Place property in `./config/application.yaml`

   ```json
   server:
       port: 7788
   ```

   and run:

   ```bash
    java -jar <path/to/my/jar>
   ```
7. Place property in `./application.properties`

   ```pl
   server.port=7788
   ```

   and run:

   ```bash
    java -jar <path/to/my/jar>
   ```
8. Place property in `./application.yaml`

   ```json
   server:
       port: 7788
   ```

   and run:

   ```bash
    java -jar <path/to/my/jar>
   ```

---

You can combine above methods all together, and the former configuration in the list take precedence over the latter one.

For example:

```bash
SERVER_PORT=2266 java -Dserver.port=5566 -jar <path/to/my/jar> --server.port=7788
```

The server will start and listen on port 7788.

This is very useful providing default properties in PropertySources with lower precedence (and usually packaged in the archive or coded in the source), and then override it in the runtime environment. And it is the design philosophy of Spring Boot:

> Be opinionated out of the box, but get out of the way quickly as requirements start to diverge from the defaults.

---

`SERVER_NAME` to `server.name` conversion was done by [Relaxed Binding](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding).

Answer (score 139):

Also, you can configure the port programmatically.

For Spring Boot 2.x.x:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomContainer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {
  public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory factory){
    factory.setPort(8042);
  }
}
```

For older versions:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return (container -> {
            container.setPort(8012);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working and very useful, when you have port in your own config file and want to set it during runtime.

Comment: This was helpful when i needed to deploy an application to a AWS Elastic Beanstalk service, to get the port from an environment variable.

Comment: This is super useful when all you want is a self-contained unit or integration test, +1.

Comment: Very useful when the env variable for port is already defined under a different name.

Comment: Is'nt it the `@Configuration` instead of `@Controller`? Please update if so.

Comment: It should be `@Configuration`, but if you import it using `@Import` it works, not sure if it is working with auto configuration search.

Comment: For a beginner: I tried creating a file `PortConfiguration.java` in the package folder and pasted this code here. However, I'm geting an error from VS code: Configuration cannot be resolved to a type. Any suggestions?

Comment: interesting, I didn't know that it is possible to do it programmatically. Thanks for info

Answer (score 111):

If you would like to run it locally, use this -

```bash
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments='-Dserver.port=8085'
```

As of **Spring Boot 2.0**, here's the command that works:

```bash
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8085
```

clues were at:

- [Maven spring boot run debug with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36217949)

Comment: Starting from Spring Boot 2, you should use `spring-boot.run.jvmArguments`.

Comment: `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments` works with Spring Boot 3

Comment: For the first command is valid wihout `''` too - therefore `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments=-Dserver.port=8085` works. Tested on SB 3.1.1

Answer (score 98):

You can set port in java code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put("server.port", 9999);

new SpringApplicationBuilder()
    .sources(SampleController.class)                
    .properties(props)
    .run(args);
```

Or in application.yml:

```
server:
    port: 9999
```

Or in application.properties:

```
server.port=9999
```

Or as a command line parameter:

```
-Dserver.port=9999
```

Comment: Using the HashMap will work only if no port is set in applications.properties or .yml.

Comment: I have a 2nd "application" class as a utility, and I wanted to only set a different port in that one. Therefore all the config file based approaches were not helpful for me. Close to giving up I found your programatic approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 62):

In case you are using `application.yml` add the Following lines to it

```
server:
     port: 9000
```

and of course 0 for random port.

Comment: this didn't seem to work. I used server.port in the application.yml and it worked

Comment: Also, make sure to keep a space between the : and the value.

Answer (score 53):

As explained in [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-use-short-command-line-arguments), there are several ways to do that:

Either you set the port in the command line (for example 8888)

`-Dserver.port=8888` or `--server.port=8888`

Example : `java -jar -Dserver.port=8888 test.jar`

Or you set the port in the application.properties

```
server.port=${port:4588}
```

or (in application.yml with yaml syntax)

```
server:
   port: ${port:4588}
```

If the port passed by -Dport (or -Dserver.port) is set in command line then this port will be taken into account. If not, then the port will be 4588 by default.

If you want to enforce the port in properties file whatever the environment variable, you just have to write:

```
server.port=8888
```

Answer (score 43):

Include below property in `application.properties`

```
server.port=8080
```

Comment: This doesn't work. What application.properties? Which properties can overwrite this one? How can I be sure Spring is picking it up?

Answer (score 31):

When you need a programatically way of doing it, you can set it during startup:

```
System.getProperties().put( "server.port", 80 );
SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
```

This might help  for things like environment dependent port. 
Have a nice day

Comment: `System.setProperty("server.port", 80);` is another way to achieve the same.

Comment: @hd1, I added our answers to the main answer, check it out and modify as you se fit please

Answer (score 21):

if you are using gradle as the build tool, you can set the server port in your **application.yml** file as:

```
server:
  port: 8291
```

If you are using maven then the port can be set in your **application.properties** file as:

```
server.port: 8291
```

Comment: for application.properties its `server.port = 8291`

Comment: What do Maven and Gradle have to do with whether you use a properties or YAML file? The build process (Maven) is completely disparate from the application framework (Spring Boot).

Answer (score 20):

To extend other answers:

There is a section in the docs for testing which explains how to configure the port on integration tests:

- [41.3 Testing Spring Boot applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)
- [41.3.3 Working with random ports](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-working-with-random-ports)

---

At integration tests, the port configuration is made using the annotation `@SpringBootTest` and the `webEnvironment` values.

---

#### Random port:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

You can inject the value using `@LocalServerPort` which is the same as `@Value("${local.server.port}")`.

- Example:

Random port test configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ExampleTest {
   ...
   @LocalServerPort //to inject port value
   int port;
}
```

---

#### Defined port:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
```

It takes the value from `server.port` if is defined.

- If is defined using `@TestPropertySource(properties = "server.port=9192")`, it overrides other defined values.
- If not, it takes the value from `src/test/resources/application.properties` (if exists).
- And finally, if it is not defined it starts with the default `8080`.

Example:

Defined port test configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "server.port=9192")
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can specify port by overriding `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean within your configuration (java based or xml). There you can specify port for used embedded servlet container. Please, see [Spring Boot - Core](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) "Embedded Servlet Container Support" paragraph and example there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Direct link: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-tomcat

Comment: Here's a current link to the programmatic override section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-customizing-embedded-containers

Answer (score 19):

In `application.properties` file present in resources:

```
server.port=8082
```

Answer (score 19):

There are three ways to do it depending on the application configuration file you are using

a) If you are using **application.properties** file set

`server.port = 8090`

b) If you are using **application.yml** file set server port property in YAML format as given below

```
server:
     port: 8090
```

c) You can also Set the property as the System property in the **main method**

```
System.setProperty("server.port","8090");
```

Answer (score 15):

Add this in your `application.properties` file

```
server.port= 8080
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) please look at [answer]

Comment: Why to add same asnwer one year later?!? and `server.port 8080` is wrong syntax for Java property file...

Answer (score 15):

There are many other stuffs you can alter in server configuration by changing application.properties.
Like session time out, address and port etc. Refer below post

ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

I used few of them as below.

```
server.session.timeout=1
server.port = 3029
server.address= deepesh
```

Answer (score 14):

1. As everyone said, you can specify in application.properties 
   **server.port = 9000** (could be any other value)
2. If you are using spring actuator in your project, by default it points to
   8080, and if you want to change it, then in application.properties mention
    
   **management.port = 9001** (could be any other value)

Answer (score 14):

In the `application.properties` file, add this line:

`server.port = 65535`

**where to place that fie:**

> 24.3 Application Property Files
>
> SpringApplication loads properties from application.properties files
>   in the following locations and adds them to the Spring Environment:
>
> ```
> A /config subdirectory of the current directory
> The current directory
> A classpath /config package
> The classpath root
> ```
>
> The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations
>   higher in the list override those defined in lower locations).

In my case I put it in the directory where the `jar` file stands.

From:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Answer (score 14):

By default spring boot app start with embedded tomcat server start at default port 8080. spring provides you with following different customization you can choose one of them.

> **NOTE** – you can use **server.port=0** spring boot will find any unassigned http random port 
>   for us.

**1) application.properties**

```
server.port=2020
```

**2) application.yml**

```
server:  
     port : 2020
```

**3) Change the server port programatically**

**3.1) By implementing  WebServerFactoryCustomizer interface - Spring 2.x**

```
@Component
public class MyTomcatWebServerCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        // customize the factory here
        factory.setPort(2020);
    }
}
```

**3.2) By Implementing EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer interface - Spring 1.x**

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        // customize here
        container.setPort(2020);
    }
}
```

**4) By using command line option**

```
 java -jar spring-boot-app.jar -Dserver.port=2020
```

Answer (score 12):

Indeed, the easiest way is to set the *server.port* property.

If you are using STS as IDE, from version 3.6.7 you actually have *Spring Properties Editor* for opening the properties file.

This editor provides autocomplete for all Spring Boot properties. If you write *port* and hit CTRL + SPACE, *server.port* will be the first option.

Comment: Or Also if you are using Intellij IDEA the autocomplete works too. ;)

Answer (score 12):

By default, spring-web module provides an embedded tomcat server that is running under the port number 8080.  If you need to change the port number of the application then go to `application.properties` file and configure the port number by using `server.port` property.

```
  server.port= 9876
```

then your application is running under the port 9876.

Answer (score 11):

Using property server.port=8080 for instance like mentioned in other answers is definitely a way to go. Just wanted to mention that you could also expose an environment property:

```
SERVER_PORT=8080
```

Since spring boot is able to replace "." for "_" and lower to UPPER case for environment variables in recent versions.
This is specially useful in containers where all you gotta do is define that environment variable without adding/editing `application.properties` or passing system properties through command line (i.e `-Dserver.port=$PORT`)

Comment: `SERVER_PORT=8081 mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 11):

Hope this one help

```
application.properties=> 

server.port=8090

application.yml=> 

server
  port:8090
```

Comment: application.yml => 

server:
  port: 8090

Answer (score 9):

You can add the port in below methods.

1. Run -> Configurations section
2. In `application.xml` add `server.port=XXXX`

Comment: Do you mean `application.yml` and what IDE are you using? Please be specific.

Answer (score 9):

Just have a `application.properties` in `src/main/resources` of the project and give there

```
server.port=****
```

where `****` refers to the port number.

Answer (score 9):

1.1 Update via a properties file.

**/src/main/resources/application.properties**

server.port=8888

**Update via a yaml file.**

```
   server:

     port: 8888
```

**EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer**

```
@Component
public class CustomContainer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

        container.setPort(8888);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

Providing the port number in application.properties file will resolve the issue

```
 server.port = 8080
```

"port depends on your choice, where you want to host the application"

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `SERVER_PORT` environment variable to configure Spring Boot port. Just set the environment variable and restart the app:

```
set SERVER_PORT=9999 // on windows machine
export SERVER_PORT=9999 // on linux
```

Please note that if you do not set those environment variables system wide, you should run the boot app on the same session.

Answer (score 8):

Mostly springboot runs on `port:8080` because of embedded Tomcat. In some it may throw an error `port 8080 already in use`. To avoid this kind of issues we can config the server port.

### Using application.properties

add `server.port=9898`

### On runtime config

run your application with below arguments.

`spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments='-Dserver.port=8081'`

Comment: This answer is outdated. You need to use the following arguments `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments='-Dserver.port=8081'` , see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66370832/179014

Comment: I've confirmed it works in SB 3.1.1 - BTW is not necessary use `''`, therefore is `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-Dserver.port=8081` works

Answer (score 8):

By Default Spring-web module provides an embedded tomcat server runs on port number 8080.

**You can change it as follows -**

A) If you are using gradle then use can set the property in your application.yml  :

```
 server:  
      port: 8042
```

B) If you are using maven then you can set the property in your application.properties :

```
server.port: 8042
```

C) When you have port in your own config file and want to set it during runtime.

By implementing WebServerFactoryCustomizer interface - Spring 2.x

```
@Component
public class MyTomcatWebServerCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        // customize the factory here
        factory.setPort(8042);
    }
}
```

By Implementing EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer interface - Spring 1.x

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        // customize here
        container.setPort(8042);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree A) and B) should be your options if you are not doing anything weird

Answer (score 7):

You can set that in application.properties under /src/main/resources/

```
server.port = 8090
```

Comment: this has been answered in more detail above

Answer (score 7):

Using mvn shell command line, spring-boot 2:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments='-Dserver.port=8085'
```

Answer (score 7):

Running by Gradle:

- Run in default port(8080): `./gradlew bootRun`
- Run in provided port(8888): `./gradlew bootRun --args='--server.port=8888'`
- If we have any variable in the `application.properties` file named `PORT`, run this: `PORT=8888 ./gradlew bootRun`

Running by Maven:

- Run in default port(8080): `mvnw spring-boot:run`
- Run in provided port(8888): `mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments='-Dserver.port=8085'`
- Run in provided port(8888): `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments='--server.port=8085'`
- Run in provided port(8888) with other custom property: `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--server.port=8899 --your.custom.property=custom"`
- If we have any variable in the `application.properties` file named `PORT`, run this: `SERVER_PORT=9093 mvn spring-boot:run`

Using `java -jar`:

- Create the .jar file:

  - For Gradle: `./gradlew clean build`. We will find the jar file inside: `build/libs/` folder.
  - For Maven: `mvn clean install`. We will find the jar file inside:`target` folder.
- Run in default port(8080): `java -jar myApplication. jar`
- Run in provided port(8888): `java -jar myApplication.jar --port=8888`
- Run in provided port(8888): `java -jar -Dserver.port=8888  myApplication.jar`
- Run in provided port(8888) having variable `SERVER_PORT` in application.properties file: `SERVER_PORT=8888 java -jar target/myApplication.jar`

Answer (score 5):

You can configure your port in application.properties file in the resources folder of your spring boot project.

```
server.port="port which you need"
```

Answer (score 5):

Open the application.properties file in your spring boot application. And add the below property in the properties file.

```
server.port = 1443
```

This will be working fine and you can set any port number as per your wish.

Answer (score 4):

"**server.port=8080**" will only works if your running application as a jar through main method,

This configuration will not work if your running this application as a war file through tomcat container.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to run apps as jar file in command environment, just type "SERVER_PORT=*** " as prefix. The full command to execute will look like below:

```
SERVER_PORT=8080 java -jar ***.jar
```

If you wanna run app in background in Linux, command with 'nohup' will look like below:

```
SERVER_PORT=8080 nohup java -jar ***.jar &
```

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways to do it

1 Set server.port property in `application.properties` file

```
server.port = 8090
```

2 Set server port property in `application.yml` file

```
server:
     port: 8090
```

3 Set the property as system property in `main` method

```
System.setProperty("server.port","8090");
```

Answer (score 4):

Just set the environment variable `SERVER_PORT`.
*(The examples works on `Linux`)*

- Start via **java -jar**:
  `SERVER_PORT=9093 java -jar target/eric-sc-dummy.jar`
- Start via **maven spring-boot plugin**:
  `SERVER_PORT=9093 mvn spring-boot:run`

Tips:

- If you add other sub commands before the `java -jar` or `mvn` command, then you need to add `export` to set env in a separate command, and split them via `;`, to make sure it's available to sub process.
  e.g:
  `export SERVER_PORT=9093; export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx256m -Xms64m"; mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the port in the **application.property** file or **application.yaml** file which is in **src/main/resources** .

**server.port=8080**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Via

> application.properties

`server.port = 8082` (or any new port number)

> 

via

> application.yml

```
server
  port: 8082
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from all the answers, I would like to point out that most IDE (IntelliJ with Spring plugin, STS) have a feature where it suggests all the configuration keys supported by SpringBoot. (i.e. all the opinionated configuration keywords)

[image]

[Spring Plugin for Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html)

Answer (score 3):

Server port declare in two types

1.static type

```
   server.port=8080. // your port number
```

2. Dynamic type

   ```
    server.port=0.      // randomly generate port number. 
    server.port=${PORT:0}
   ```

Comment: Why are there dots behind the given port '8080.' and '0.' ?

Answer (score 2):

The default port is : 8080 but we can customize the port number in application.properties
as shown below

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.port = 5050 -- #here we can give any port number.
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is the first result if you google for **Gradle Spring Port**.

If you use gradle you can do something like this if you have the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin already applied:

```
bootRun {
    args += ["--server.port=[PORT]"]
}
```

For a more sophisticated answer please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198101/1414695).

Answer (score 2):

If you are working over boot projects and you wanna configure the port you can give the input in the application.properties file like
NOTE:properties file should be under src/main/resource

### Spring properties

> **server.port=9999**
> If you using the CMD then follow this command
> **-Dserver.port=9999**
> For default port its server.port=0
> Make sure no port is using this port number

Answer (score 2):

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/36865796/1587329 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40799750/1587329, **a gradle one-liner** would be

```
SERVER_PORT=9090 gradle bootRun
```

Answer (score 2):

In Application properties just add 1 line

```
server.port = 8090
```

Comment: it's a dublicate answer

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically, with spring boot 2.1.5:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory server) {
        server.setPort(9000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

Added a custom container class :

```
@Component
public class CustomContainer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer configurableEmbeddedServletContainer) {
       configurableEmbeddedServletContainer.setPort(8888);
    }

}
```

But this was still not using port 8888.

Then I set "scanBasePackages" property like this on "@SpringBootApplication" class on my main method: `(scanBasePackages = {"custom container package"})`

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.javabrains.util"})
public class CourseApiApp {

    public static void main (String args []) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

And it started picking up port set in Custom Container.

Answer (score 1):

In spring boot you can easily configure the service exposing port in `application.properties` file.

```
server.port=portnumber
```

if you don't set a port specifically, then it will try to open the service with port `80`. in case if it is already used, service will not be started on the embedded container.

Answer (score 1):

if your port number can be random you can use random function in your `application.properties` `server.port=${random.int(4)}`

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where you would want to have random port number

Answer (score 1):

`server.port = 0` for random port

`server.port` = 8080 for custom 8080 port

Answer (score 1):

in the file application.properties add the following:
server.port=8888
THE PORT NEEDED ALWAYS MENTIONED HERE

Answer (score 1):

Aside from adding the port on application.properties, you  can also easily achieve multiple ports for different environments,  by combining the property files approach with Spring profiles. Specifically, we can create a property file for each environment.

For example, we'll have an application-dev.properties file with this content:

```
server.port=8081
```

Then you can  add another application-qa.properties file with a different port:

```
server.port=8082
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure the port details in *Config file* or application properties.

e.g.

```
port =8876
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are use the spring command line interface (CLI) use the `--` to separate commands from the `spring` command arguments, to change the port:

`spring run hello.groovy -- --server.port=9000`

[spring-boot cli](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#cli)

Answer (score 0):

Many parameters including server port can be changed in multiple ways. However there is an order of precedence as outlined below:

1. First precedence is assigned to custom code like below:

`@Component
public class CustomConfiguration implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.setPort(9090);      
    }
}`

Here we are setting server port as 9090 which is hard coded in the code. To avoid hardcoding, we can assign a value from environment using @Value annotation in a bean class and the use it here.

2. Second precedence is assigned to command line arguments like below:

   java -jar target/spring-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar **--server.port=8092**

Here we are telling the server to start listening at 8092. Note if we use both the above approaches together, it will ignore command line argument as custom code is given the first precedence.

3. Third precedence is assigned to OS environment variable. If none of the above two approaches is taken up, Spring will take server port from environment property. In case of deployment on Kubernetes, a property set under env section in Deployment yaml will be used.
4. Fourth precedence is assigned to profile specific application.properties file.
5. Fifth precedence is assigned to value assigned in application.properties file (which by default Spring Boot tries to find src/main/resources/config, if not found, then tries to find under src/main/resources).

Most manageable and useful approach can be combination of first and third approach. You can use an environment property and use that custom code.

Sample code:

`import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class EnvironmentCustomizer {
    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int serverPort;
    public void setServerPort(int serverPort) {
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
    }
    public int getServerPort() {
        return serverPort;
    }
}`



`@Configuration
public class CustomConfiguration
{
    @Autowired
    EnvironmentCustomizer envCustomizer;
    @Bean
    WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> webServerPortCustomizer() {
    return factory -> factory.setPort(envCustomizer.getServerPort());
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Kotlin approach for setting the port in code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<TestApplication>(*args) {
        setDefaultProperties(mapOf(
            "server.port" to 8081
        ))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to application.properties file and give custom port name i.e., server.port=8081

Answer (score 0):

Using application.properties:

Create or open the application.properties file in your Spring Boot project's src/main/resources directory if it doesn't already exist.

Add the following line to specify the desired port (e.g., 8080):

server.port=8080

Replace 8080 with the port number you want to use.

Save the application.properties file and Start the Application.[image]

Answer (score -1):

put this code in u applicatop.properties file 
[image]

Comment: The file name is incorrect.

Answer (score -3):

In my case adding statement

```
server.port=${port:8081}
```

override the default tomcat server port.