# Running Spring app built with gradle on Heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, deployment, gradle

I have problem with my Spring application built with Gradle. App includes MongoDB(MongoHQ from Heroku).

I managed how to push everything on heroku, I've added this code to my project:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoHQConfiguration {

    public @Bean MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws MongoException, UnknownHostException {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoURI(System.getenv("MONGOHQ_URL")));
    }

    public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

After changing buildpacks to one with gradle, I pushed everything on Heroku free account with MongoHQ Sandbox.

But after trying to run my app through web browser, I'm getting this error:

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

`heroku logs` gives me this output:

> 2014-10-15T18:19:30.293964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -jar build/libs/*.jar`
>
> 2014-10-15T18:19:30.797673+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/*.jar
>
> 2014-10-15T18:19:31.474525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>
> 2014-10-15T18:19:31.464753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>
> 2014-10-15T18:19:32.577398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tvmaniac.herokuap
>   p.com request_id=7e8bfe6c-2669-405e-9bce-59fde09f71ef fwd="89.129.247.185" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2014-10-15T18:19:34.016281+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tvmani
>   ac.herokuapp.com request_id=4300386e-dc5c-47ed-9878-0bee87128fc9 fwd="89.129.247.185" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2014-10-15T18:19:41.988204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tvmaniac.herokuap
>   p.com request_id=436db871-ea8c-428f-8cc7-160c3cb96a2d fwd="50.16.146.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

I think the problem is in Procfile, but I have no idea what should I add there, here's my current code:

> default_process_types:
>
> web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/*.jar

**EDITED**

Here's my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.8.RELEASE")
    }
}    

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

mainClassName = "com.shalastra.tvmaniac.TVManiacConfiguration"

jar {
    baseName = 'tvmaniac'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
    maven { url "http://m2.neo4j.org" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testCompile("junit:junit")

    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb")

    compile("com.google.guava:guava:17.0")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.0'
}

task stage(dependsOn: ['clean', 'build', 'installApp'])
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why don't You add a task that copies the built artifact from `build/lib` to `project.rootDir` (renaming it appropriately) and start application from the root dir? It seems that there's no jar built.

Comment: Can you explain how I can do it?

Comment: I'll add a response in a minute.

Comment: Ok, once again. It seems that there's a jar file missing. How You provide that jar? Do You run gradle on heroku or commit the built spring-boot app (jar) to heroku with source control?

Comment: I'm using this buildpack: [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks], that's it. It's my first gradle app on heroku, so maybe I missed something.

Comment: Have You done everything according to these instructions: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle ?

Comment: And also, can You share You build.gradle please?

Comment: I think so, I've edited question and added build.gradle

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After a short discussion in comments it seems (according to [this](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle) instructions) that You need add the following task to `build.gradle` file:

```
task stage(type: Copy, dependsOn: [clean, build]) {
    from jar.archivePath
    into project.rootDir 
    rename {
        'app.jar'
    }
}
stage.mustRunAfter(clean)

clean << {
    project.file('app.jar').delete()
}
```

And the content of `Procfile` will be:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar
```

Now it should work fine.

Explanation:

Task `stage` prepares jar file to be run. After it's finished the output jar is copied into `project.rootDir` and renamed to `app.jar`. It guarantees that it will have always the same name and can be easily run with the command from `Procfile`. `stage` task also depends on `clean` (which has an additional action to remove `app.jar`) and `build` (which builds the app). It's important to set `stage.mustRunAfter(clean)` because otherwise the order in which tasks are run is not determined (this probably happens now - check it locally). What I mean is if just `dependsOn` is specified `build` may be run, then `clean` and finally `stage` - and nothing is created. I hope it's clear.

Comment: This paste bin has been removed.

Comment: This is a different problem. What You were asking about has been solved. See this question for port configuration for spring boot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/spring-boot-how-to-configure-port. Basically You need the app to port number from $PORT environment variable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. So I should create application.properties in resources folder and write there this: `server.port = 8080`? Or should I do something else? Because adding this still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately You can't specify the port in application.properties for heroku, You need to take the one defined under $PORT. Maybe try adding `-Dserver.port=$PORT` to Procfile?

Comment: Ok, it's working now. If anyone will need solution, here it is. Procfile should look like this: `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar app.jar`

Answer (score 5):

I've made an example so noobies can really check out and understand every line of code. Because I really know how frustrating this can be to figure out.

This is what your Procfile should look like

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar app.jar
```

This is what your Gradle file should look like

```
group 'com.springtest.api'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

//Path to the Main Web Class
mainClassName = "hello.Application"

jar {
    baseName = 'spring-test-api'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'

    // Spring Framework
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.6'
}

task stage(type: Copy, dependsOn: [clean, build]) {
    from jar.archivePath
    into project.rootDir
    rename {
        'app.jar'
    }
}
stage.mustRunAfter(clean)

clean << {
    project.file('app.jar').delete()
}
```

If the `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` aren't in your main project directory or is not up-to-date then in cmd run the command `gradle wrapper`.

If you don't have Gradle actually installed on your computer install it from the main gradle website.

My example on github is below.
https://github.com/arose13/Heroku-Spring-Gradle_Example

Comment: This should be the official gradle springboot heroku example, not some vague tutorial on their official website: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku +1