# Gradle app doesn't start

Tags: heroku, groovy, gradle

I'm experimenting with deploying a Gradle app on Heroku. Here is the code: https://github.com/sarbogast/spark-groovy-hello-world/tree/master

When I run 'gradle stage' and the command in Procfile locally, it works. But when I push to Heroku, the app crashes and the log says it can't find the script:

bash: build/install/spark-groovy-hello-world/bin/spark-groovy-hello-world: No such file or directory

I'm still a beginner with Heroku, so I don't understand everything about how it works.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out: I was missing a settings.gradle file in the root of my project, with the following line in it: rootProject.name = "spark-groovy-hello-world"

Now the app doesn't work yet, because I have a port problem, but that's another issue.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389679/running-spring-app-built-with-gradle-on-heroku/26391103#26391103. Might be helpful.