# Spring Boot Gradle app on Heroku: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: java, spring, heroku, spring-boot

I have a spring boot gradle app which I could run successfully on my PC by doing:

```
heroku local
```

It can also deploy on heroku successfully when I go:

```
git push heroku master
```

This is my result:

```
Counting objects: 17, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 596 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Fetching set buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle... done

remote: -----> Gradle app detected
remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Building Gradle app...
remote:        WARNING: The Gradle buildpack is currently in Beta.
remote: -----> executing ./gradlew build
remote:        :compileJavaNote: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
remote:        Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
remote:
remote:        :processResources
remote:        :classes
remote:        :jar
remote:        :bootRepackage
remote:        :assemble
remote:        :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
remote:        :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
remote:        :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
remote:        :test UP-TO-DATE
remote:        :check UP-TO-DATE
remote:        :build
remote:
remote:        BUILD SUCCESSFUL
remote:
remote:        Total time: 11.935 secs
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 72.3MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v9
remote:        https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
   6326429..291326d  master -> master
```

But when I try to access it on heroku, it crashes. The heroku logs says this:

```
2015-12-11T17:05:46.096985+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 291326d by xxx@gmail.com
2015-12-11T17:05:46.097021+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by xxx@gmail.com
2015-12-11T17:05:46.378258+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-12-11T17:05:46.378269+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-12-11T17:05:46.755655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-12-11T17:05:53.121398+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=5000 -jar  build/libs/myapp.jar`
2015-12-11T17:05:54.260741+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/myapp.jar
2015-12-11T17:05:54.784064+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-12-11T17:05:54.773714+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-12-11T17:05:54.788248+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

Why is it `Unable to access jarfile build/libs/myapp.jar` ?

When I navigate to that folder on my local PC, the jarfile is there.

I'm running out of ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Are you sure your JAR's name is `myapp.jar`? Isn't something like `myapp-[version].jar`? Can you run your application locally with the same command Heroku is using (`java -Dserver.port=5000 -jar  build/libs/myapp.jar`)?

Comment: Also try running `heroku run ls build/libs` to see if the file is there on Heroku

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually found a very helpful thread here: [Running Spring app built with gradle on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389679/running-spring-app-built-with-gradle-on-heroku?rq=1)

Which helped me with my problem - this thread seems to be more detail than Heroku's official guide.

You must add the following code to your build.gradle file:

```
task stage(type: Copy, dependsOn: [clean, build]) {
    from jar.archivePath
    into project.rootDir
    rename {
        'app.jar'
    }
}
stage.mustRunAfter(clean)

clean << {
    project.file('app.jar').delete()
}
```

Then, point your Procfile to the app.jar:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to modify your stage task for that.

In your gradle.build file, make sure to give a name to your built artifact like this.

```
jar {
    baseName = 'app'
    version = '0.0.1'
}
```

With that been done, and the following in `Procfile`, it should just run fine.

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/app-0.0.1.jar
```

I found that if name is not explicitly defined, heroku seems to name the artifact something like `build-{buildNumber}.jar` and no wonder it will never find the `app.jar`.

Also, if not set already, the build pack needs to be set.

```
heroku config:set GRADLE_TASK="build"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku):

> The Gradle buildpack will automatically detect the use of the Spring Boot and Ratpack web frameworks.

The `web` command should be overridden only if needed. If you're using Spring Boot, you shouldn't need to specify a `Procfile` at all.

Delete it, and get your app running without further configuration.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

I was also encountering the same error and it was a serious waste of time for me. Unlike the ones here, I solved the problem as follows.

First of all, we need to know this.

> Heroku creates a new version after each build.

For this reason, if you use a command that contains a fixed version definition in the `Procfile` file like `build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, it will cause an error like this.

```
2022-03-02T18:19:30.797673+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

After the build task, `Gradle` creates 2 jars named `app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar` under `libs/` folder. `app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` is our application including all dependencies. So I first blocked the rendering of `app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar` as below.

```
jar {
    enabled = false
}
```

Then I used the following wildcard definition in `Procfile` which is not affected by version changes.

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

The problem can also be solved in this way.

Answer (score 0):

For deploying Gradle App on Heroku. Just add below lines in build.gradle file.

```
    task stage(type: Copy, dependsOn: [clean, build]) {
    from jar.archivePath
    into project.rootDir
    rename {
        'app.jar'
    }
}
stage.mustRunAfter(clean)
```

This also in build.gradle file for running jar file.

```
 jar {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.MF'
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.heroku.herokudemo.HerokuDemoApplication'
        )
    }
}
```

After this create a txt file named Procfile and add the following content.

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar build/libs/heroku-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```