# Error when deploy Gradle project to Heroku

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to build a Spring Boot application in Heroku, but apparently, they can't find the JAR file

```
2018-02-22T14:54:06.434832+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-02-22T14:54:06.350652+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-02-22T14:54:06.359456+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/algamoney*.jar
2018-02-22T14:54:06.667596+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I created profile:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -Dspring.profiles.active=prod $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/algamoney*.jar
```

I've found some similar questions here in Stack overflow and the solution is put some tasks in the `build.gradle` file, but it still doesn't work. Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.algaworks.algamoney-api'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2')
    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compile('org.flywaydb:flyway-core')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-java8')    
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310')  
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'

    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

I've looked for a lot of possible solutions, even in the heroku documentation, but I still not find any solution which could solve my problem.

Comment: What is the link of solution you seen on Stack Overflow (give links)? Check the existing of `build/libs/algamoney*.jar` manually.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228907/spring-boot-gradle-app-on-heroku-unable-to-access-jarfile

Comment: Yes, the jar file exists

Comment: Follow the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34229717/3728901 . You should put code snippet (12 lines of code) at the top of your `build.gradle` . The crux of the solution is `clean` --> copy JAR artifact