# How should I create a Java application.properties file for Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to set a property in a Spring application (`server.port`). To do this, the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port) says that I need a `application.properties` file. It says this as it is a default thing for all Java applications. So, how/where should I create this file?

I've followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21083284/4419675), but I had no success creating the file under `/src/main/resources/`. Is it missing a reference?

EDIT: I had no success because the application still loads using port 8080 instead of the port that I've defined in the configuration file.

Comment: You've to register `PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer` to load properties file.

Comment: @RohitJain Not with spring-boot. (I mean not explicitly. It's done for you.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh, I didn't know that. In fact, haven't used spring boot till now :)

Comment: I'd ask that you provide your configuration and your startup procedure, how you launch your program. If there's a `application.properties` in the root of the classpath, spring-boot will find it.

Comment: another thing to check: How do you build / start / dependency manage your application? Gradle or maven should include the path to the classpath. But if you are building a pure java app with an IDE with plain spring-boot lib (and dependend libs) you have to configure the path inside the IDE (and later by hand for running as a standalone-app).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I'm using maven and starting the application with Eclipse. What do you mean with "in the root of the classpath"? My classpath is in `/application/.classpath` and the application.properties file is in `/application/src/main/resources/application.properties`

Comment: @meistermeier, How would I reference the file? I've just placed where the link suggested. I believe that I'm missing how to reference this file. Regarding my environment, I'm following the standard spring.io example using Eclipse and Maven. It is working, but I need to change the server port.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, thank you! Placing the file at the root of my solution (next to the .classpath file) fixed the problem! If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @user4419675 if your eclipse setup does not respect the resources directory, spring boot will not find the file. I don't know how well eclipse works out of the box with a maven controlled projects and later added conventional folders (like src/main/resources). I think it is just missing from the classpath in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are running Spring Boot,go to `application.properties` and then set

```
server.port=8081
```