# change kurento test port

Tags: java, spring-boot, webrtc, kurento

I am trying to integrate kurento in my VPS server,with the help of

http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorials/java/tutorial-helloworld.html

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world
git checkout 6.4.0
mvn compile exec:java
```

My problem is ,the port 8443 is already assigned for parallel plesk.So i am not able to use this port for kurento.Is there any way to change the test port from 8443?

I have updated the port in src/main/resources/application.properties and tried with `mvn compile -e exec:java -Dserver.port=8089`,but still this is not working

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Kurento Java Tutorial - One2One Call Advanced 6.4.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-java-version) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create-timestamp (get-build-timestamp) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (get-scm-revision) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/var/www/vhosts/vps72185.vps.ovh.ca/mysite.co.uk/kurento-flabba/kurento-one2one-call-recording' && 'git' 'rev-parse' '--verify' 'HEAD'
[INFO] Working directory: /var/www/vhosts/vps72185.vps.ovh.ca/mysite.co.uk/kurento-flabba/kurento-one2one-call-recording
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: 9fba36e32343bb490384a4e1869e2b40de78fa2e at timestamp: 1460955195622
[WARNING] Cannot get the branch information from the git repository: 
Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref

[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/var/www/vhosts/vps123.vps.ovh.ca/mysite.co.uk/kurento-flabba/kurento-one2one-call-recording' && 'git' 'rev-parse' '--verify' 'HEAD'
[INFO] Working directory: /var/www/vhosts/vps123.vps.ovh.ca/mysite.co.uk/kurento-flabba/kurento-one2one-call-recording
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: UNKNOWN
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (default) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 325 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---

   .------------------------------------.
   |                                    |
   |   | |/ /  _ _ _ ___ _ _| |_ ___    |
   |   | ' < || | '_/ -_) ' \  _/ _ \   |
   |   |_|\_\_,_|_| \___|_||_\__\___/   |
   |                                    |
   '------------------------------------'
                    version 6.4.0

00:53:17.662 [OneCallRecApp.main()] INFO  - o.k.t.one2onecallrec.One2OneCallRecApp   -
                Starting One2OneCallRecApp on vps123.vps.ovh.ca with PID 23974 (/var/www/vhosts/vps123.vps.ovh.ca/mysite.co.uk/kurento-flabba/kurento-one2one-call-recording/target/classes started by root in /var/www/vhosts/vps123.vps.ovh.ca/mysite.co.uk/kurento-flabba/kurento-one2one-call-recording)
00:53:17.665 [OneCallRecApp.main()] DEBUG - o.k.t.one2onecallrec.One2OneCallRecApp   -
                Running with Spring Boot v1.3.0.RELEASE, Spring v4.2.3.RELEASE
00:53:17.665 [OneCallRecApp.main()] INFO  - o.k.t.one2onecallrec.One2OneCallRecApp   -
                No profiles are active
00:53:17.975 [     pool-1-thread-1] INFO  - o.h.validator.internal.util.Version      -
                HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.2.Final
```

ERRORS
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorials are spring-boot applications. You can change the port where the application is served from the command line. Just add the `server.port` flag when invoking the `exec` maven plugin

`mvn compile exec:java -Dserver.port=<port>`

There is an answer to this also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/spring-boot-how-to-configure-port)

The application must be started with a KMS running locally. Otherwise, you'll need the flag `-Dkms.url=ws://<ip>:8888/kurento`. Once it starts, you will be able to access your application in `https://localhost:<port>`. Please note that the app is served through a secure connection.

---

EDIT 1

This line from your logs

> Caused by: org.kurento.commons.exception.KurentoException:
>   [KurentoClient]  Exception connecting to WebSocket server
>   ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento

indicates that KMS is not running in that machine, or that it's running in a different port. Please do make sure the KMS process is indeed running when you launch the application.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer,I tried this.but still it is not working ,I updated my question.

Comment: @Shijin I think the output that you posted is not full. Do you get any errors? Is your KMS up? Remember the app is server through https.

Comment: I uploaded the errors,sorry it is large in size,so i converted as image

Comment: @Shijin For such big output, I would use an external hosting service, and provide a link. Are you sure you are running KMS in the same machine? Please read the whole answer, as there is info about what to do if KMS is running in a different machine.

Comment: @KMS on the same server

Comment: @Shijin Your app can't connect to your KMS. Make sure it's running.

Comment: service kurento-media-server-6.0 status
 * checking Kurento Media Server...                                              * /usr/bin/kurento-media-server is running with pid 32237...            [ OK ] is it seems kms is up?

Comment: @Shijin Yes, it seems up. Check if you changed the port where KMS is deployed, but that error is telling you that your spring-boot app can't reach your KMS instance.