# Is it possible to set properties for a Spring Boot application from a bean?

Tags: java, spring

I was wondering if there is any way to do this.

I want to hardcode a property (I know might not be the best), let's say I want to run my application always on port **XXX** or any other configuration without using a `.properties`.

Is there any way I can do this from the main? or a configuration bean?

Thanks.

Comment: yes it's possible EmbeddedServletContainerFactory

Comment: but, is there any way to do it not only for the port?

Comment: you can do pretty much every thing with the EmbeddedServletContainerFactory for Tomcat, Jetty or Undertow.

Comment: any code example?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-enable-multiple-connectors-in-tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this for how to configure a port: [Spring Boot - how to configure port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/spring-boot-how-to-configure-port)

Relevant code is this:

```
@Controller
public class ServletConfig {
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
      return (container -> {
        container.setPort(8012);
    });
}
```

In general, most properties that can be configured via application.properties can also be configured through a Java bean. But, I would suggest using `application.properties` if you can. It allows you to change properties, without having to change source code.

EDIT:

Some other code from the posted link you might find useful:

```
HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put("server.port", 9999);

new SpringApplicationBuilder()
  .sources(SampleController.class)                
  .properties(props)
  .run(args);
```

Comment: I had tried the second option but didnt work before, it works now, thanks!