# How to change the port of a Spring Boot application using Gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, port

The simple question is: **How can you change the Spring Boot application port with gradle?**

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/spring-boot-how-to-configure-port?page=2&tab=active#tab-top) are already listed a lot of correct answers if you are not using gradle. So for none gradle issues, please refere to this post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're not already using the [Spring Boot Gradle Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html) add it to your build script (of course, adapt the Spring Boot version to your needs):

```
buildscript{
    ext { springBootVersion = '1.5.7.RELEASE' }
    dependencies {
          classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

With this plugin you can do the following:

```
bootRun {
    args += ["--server.port=[PORT]"]
}
```

- obviously, replace [PORT] with the actual port number

**OR for more dynamic** you can use a project property to change the port. You have to do something similar like this:

```
if(!project.hasProperty("port"))
    project.ext.set("port", 8080)

bootRun {
    args += ["--server.port=${project.port}"]
}
```

Then you can start the application with

> ./gradlew bootRun -Pport=8888

If you skip the -Pport in this example it will use 8080.

Comment: Hmm i find this doesn't work, as I get:
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value '[port]'

Comment: You probably didn't replace [PORT] with the actual port number.

Comment: dumbo I am! Thanks!

Comment: Can I use this in order to [generate client code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65629920/how-to-create-typescript-angular-client-from-spring-boot-server-in-gradle-task)?

Answer (score 23):

In case you don't want to add extra configuration to your Gradle scripts, you can achieve it by setting the `SERVER_PORT` environment variable:

```
SERVER_PORT=8888 ./gradlew bootRun
```

**[UPDATE]** Since Gradle 4.9, it's possible to [pass arguments to `bootRun`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.1/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#running-your-application-passing-arguments) without extra configuration:

```
./gradlew bootRun --args='--server.port=8888'
```

Answer (score 7):

**Running by Gradle:**

- **Run in default port(8080):** `./gradlew bootRun`
- **Run in provided port(8888):** `./gradlew bootRun --args='--server.port=8888'`
- If we have any variable in the `application.properties` file named `PORT`, run this: `PORT=8888 ./gradlew bootRun`

**Running by Maven:**

- **Run in default port(8080):** `mvnw spring-boot:run`
- **Run in provided port(8888):** `mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments='-Dserver.port=8085'`
- **Run in provided port(8888):** `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments='--server.port=8085'`
- **Run in provided port(8888) with other custom property:** `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--server.port=8899 --your.custom.property=custom"`
- If we have any variable in the `application.properties` file named `PORT`, run this: `SERVER_PORT=9093 mvn spring-boot:run`

**Using `java -jar`:**

- **Create the .jar file:**

  - For Gradle: `./gradlew clean build`. We will find the jar file inside: `build/libs/` folder.
  - For Maven: `mvn clean install`. We will find the jar file inside:`target` folder.
- **Run in default port(8080):** `java -jar myApplication. jar`
- **Run in provided port(8888):** `java -jar myApplication.jar --port=8888`
- **Run in provided port(8888):** `java -jar -Dserver.port=8888  myApplication.jar`
- **Run in provided port(8888) having variable `SERVER_PORT` in application.properties file:** `SERVER_PORT=8888 java -jar target/myApplication.jar`