# Pass Dynamic Port from Gradle boot:run of an application

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I am having an application, which is running on some port(ex-8080) now when I start this application using gradlew I want to pass dynamic port to start the application?

./gradlew :testApplication:bootRun

is there anyway to pass the dynamic port here??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the port of a Spring Boot application using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198100/how-to-change-the-port-of-a-spring-boot-application-using-gradle)

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to `build.gradle` so that we can pass parameters to `gradlew` along to the underlying `java` command:

```
bootRun {
    if (project.hasProperty('args')) {
        args project.args.split(',')
    }
}
```

Pass the arguments you would normally send to a `java` command (in this case, overriding the `server.port`) as `-Pargs` to `gradlew`:

`/gradlew :testApplication:bootRun -Pargs="--server.port=8081"`

What is here:

- When you run java with arguments `--server.port=8081`, Spring Boot will override default property (e.g. Spring Boot will ignore your port in properties file, it will use value from command line
- `-Pargs` is the way to ask bootRun to command line arguments. See details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments).

See also the [same question for maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052857/spring-overriding-one-application-property-from-command-line).

Comment: Thanks for the info, -Pargs is not considering, I added the below things and it started working.

bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}

and then passed  -Dserver.port=8081 and It started working. I have another question , Can I able to modify the custom value specified in application.properties by passing the argument in gradlew bootRun?

example in application.properties there is a variable call

test.url="http:localhost:8081"now I am running the gradlew :testApplication:bootRun and here I wanna modify the content of test.url, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't pass the port directly.

But if you want a workaround, do the following:

- Build the application with `gradle build`.
- Navigate in your project and open the directory `build/libs`
- Now you have to see the jar of your project and then run this command `java -jar yourJarProject.jar --server.port=8081`.