# Grails Application With SpringBoot using different yml files for different environments

Tags: grails, spring-boot, gradle, yaml

I am using Grails 3.3.1 with spring boot. the build tool is gradle.
All application related properties are configured in application.yml file.

Now I want to access different .yml files for different environments [development, test etc]. For this I have created different .yml files per environment.
The command used to run server is : grails -Dgrails.env=test run-app
Now when i access any property, it gives me the values from application-test.yml file which is as expected.

But when I access server.port, it is reading this property from application.yml instead of application-test.yml.

Can anyone help me in running the application by using server.port from application-test.yml file

### The application.yml is as follows:

server:
  port: 8081

### contextPath : /ssp

### the application-test.yml is as follows:

server:
  port: 8443

### contextPath : /ssp

I am expecting the server to run on port 8443 as this property is in application-test.yml. But the server runs on port 8081 as mentioned in application.yml

Comment: port 8443 is default for https, do 'grails run-app -https'.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the above issue by adding server.port per environment in the .yml files

### #application.yml:

## environments:

```
development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: none
        url: //url
        logSql: true
        username: //username
        password: //password
        driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
    server:
        port: 8081
        contextPath : /ssp
test:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: none
        url: //url
        username: //username
        password: //password
        driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        logSql: true
    server:
        port: 8082
        contextPath : /ssp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the port directly at startup with `--server.port` or `-Dserver.port`

If you want completely different YML, you can set `spring.config.location` as a parameter. Here's an example:

```
# start service
/opt/jdk/bin/java \
  -Dserver.port=<your port> \
  -jar /opt/service/<your warfile> --spring.config.location=<your YML>
```

References:
[How to configure port for a Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/how-to-configure-port-for-a-spring-)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-use-short-command-line-argumentsboot-application