# Changing port number in Spring boot program. No application.properties

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

I just imported a java project from spring.io https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I did it in my eclipse. I want to change the port number for the embedded tomcat to run but I can't see any application.properties (there is no src/main/resources) as it used to be when I would manually create a spring boot application through File->New->...

This is how the structure looks like

[image]

I checked out manifest.yml
and even typed

server: 
  port : 9090

but it says, unknown property 'server' for type 'Cloudfoundary Manifest'

Comment: add a application.properties file by yourself and then add server port you need

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21083170/8101556)

Comment: @gladiator need to create the package as well?

Comment: yes the file should be in src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: @gladiator not able to do it. it is getting created in in the 2nd src folder.
(there are 2 srcs remember?)
If you could tell me the steps. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can add application.properties

You source folder will look like this  ignore other files

[image]

Comment: It works now! I had made the folder name as 'resource' changed it to 'resources' and it works! One last question. Where is the checking of this pattern is taking place? who is doing that?

Answer (score 6):

add application.properties in your resource folder

```
#--------------------------------
# Tomcat Port 
#----------------------------------
server.port = 8080

# ----------------------------------------
# Logging Level
# ----------------------------------------
logging.level.root=error
logging.level.org.springframework=info
logging.level.org.hibernate=error

# ----------------------------------------
# MySQL DataBase Connection Properties
# ----------------------------------------
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# ----------------------------------------
# ACTUATOR PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------
endpoints.actuator.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false

# ----------------------------------------
# DevTols PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true

# ----------------------------------------
# JSP PREFIX/POSTFIX PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------
#spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/view/
#spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```