# Application failed to start

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am starting to learn springboot and already encountered an error. I tried searching for this error, but i wasn't able to find it. I have inserted the pictures of the entire error as well as my code for the pom.xml and the main class.

pom.xml

```
  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


</project>
```

Main

```
package io.java.springbootstarter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiApp {

     public static void main(String[] args) {


          SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);
        }

   }
```

This was the description for the error:

```
The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2018-03-21 22:47:48.794  INFO 9412 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@f75083: startup date [Wed Mar 21 22:47:46 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-21 22:47:48.794  INFO 9412 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdKEW.png),
[Error Continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs16r.png)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try using port 3000

Comment: How can i change that? @Garret

Comment: The port 8080 is busy. Stop the process running on 8080 and retry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/spring-boot-how-to-configure-port

Comment: no need to be so rude to him... if you not gonna add to the chat just dont...

Comment: I was googling it while asking him @KenWhite, maybe he had encountered an easier solution then what I had come up with.

Comment: @Garret Thanks a ton! I will change it right now.

Comment: declare server.port=8081 in application properties, it might work

Comment: Thanks guys, found a simple solution and changed it to port 3000 using this : System.getProperties().put( "server.port", 3000 );

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linux/mac, u can try this command :

```
lsof -i :8080
```

This will return the process id along with other information, then use the following command to kill the process :

```
kill -9 your_process_id
```

This way, you need not to change the port anymore.

In case the other process is a java process as well, you could also just do `jps` which shows all running java processes and kill it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The port 8080 in using, you should use another port. You can config in application.properties by setting server.port

Answer (score 0):

For me just restarting my computer worked. As the error message says some application was already using the specified port.