# How do I start two instances of Spring Boot on different ports?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I tried to use this answer to start another instance of Spring Boot

[Spring Boot - how to configure port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/spring-boot-how-to-configure-port#21083284)

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=8081
```

It gave an error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start.
```

It also restarted the other instance (live reload?).

Comment: have you checked that this port is free? it is likely that the previous run didn't end correctly and it is still blocking the port. try with a different port to prove that or restart your machine for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with

```
env SERVER_PORT=8081 mvn spring-boot:run
```

It also works with (Spring Boot 1.5.x)

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--server.port=8081"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sprint Boot run/debug configuration we can use the VM Option to define port

```
 -Dserver.port=9090
```

So by defining different ports we can start multiple instances