# Where to specify a specific port number in spring boot service file in systemd?

Tags: spring-boot

Need to know where can I specify the spring boot port aa when I check my service status I get this:

"Serverkt.log started at server-name with process id"
But I don't get the port number.
Also wanted to know where I can find the spring logs in the server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure port for a Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/how-to-configure-port-for-a-spring-boot-application)

Answer (score 2):

spring boot has its configuration file. I guess that you have it included in your jar/war file. So basically unzip that file and look inside it (try to search for `application.properties` or `application.yaml|yml`).

property `server.port` defines the port on which application is running. It defaults to `8080`. 
If you are using spring-boot 2 then with property `logging.path` you can change the path where output file will be placed. However I don't know if this works when you have logback/log4j/... configuration.

if you run your application you can override those properties specified in `appplication.properties|yaml` by providing command line properties. For example you can change the port with command `java -jar your-boot.jar --server.port=9090`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're starting spring boot from a service file, you can set the port using command line arguments e.g.port 8083 would look like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/corda/spring.jar --server.port=8083
```