# Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080 while push to pivotal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I'm new in pivotal cloud foundry. I have the problem when I push the Java application, I encountered the problem in health check.

`The error was Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused`

Please help me to solve this problem

EDIT: I'm using Eureka service, Zuul and central config. when i start the application in local it running normally but when i push to PCF it gets this error message:

```
2019-09-26T17:51:08.273+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] :: Spring Boot :: (v2.1.3.RELEASE)
2019-09-26T17:51:08.423+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:08.418 INFO 18 --- [ main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : https://fo-config.cfapps.io/globalconfig
2019-09-26T17:51:08.982+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:08.981 INFO 18 --- [ main] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
2019-09-26T17:51:08.984+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:08.984 INFO 18 --- [ main] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding TrustManager for /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
2019-09-26T17:51:09.022+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:08.994 INFO 18 --- [tificates.crt-0] org.cloudfoundry.security.FileWatcher : Start watching /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
2019-09-26T17:51:09.409+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:09.409 INFO 18 --- [ main] c.s.FileWatchingX509ExtendedTrustManager : Initialized TrustManager for /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
2019-09-26T17:51:09.414+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:09.414 INFO 18 --- [ main] oundryContainerKeyManagerFactory$SunX509 : Adding System Key Manager
2019-09-26T17:51:09.426+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:09.423 INFO 18 --- [ main] oundryContainerKeyManagerFactory$SunX509 : Adding Key Manager for /etc/cf-instance-credentials/instance.key and /etc/cf-instance-credentials/instance.crt
2019-09-26T17:51:09.453+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:09.451 INFO 18 --- [-instance.crt-0] org.cloudfoundry.security.FileWatcher : Start watching /etc/cf-instance-credentials/instance.crt
2019-09-26T17:51:09.455+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:09.455 INFO 18 --- [-instance.key-0] org.cloudfoundry.security.FileWatcher : Start watching /etc/cf-instance-credentials/instance.key
2019-09-26T17:51:09.585+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:09.585 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.c.s.FileWatchingX509ExtendedKeyManager : Initialized KeyManager for /etc/cf-instance-credentials/instance.key and /etc/cf-instance-credentials/instance.crt
2019-09-26T17:51:11.629+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:11.629 INFO 18 --- [ main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=be-customer-management-development, generic-development, profiles=[cloud,development], label=null, version=1d78f7db2bedb1e0709ad852d76819406bec9fa5, state=null
2019-09-26T17:51:11.630+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:11.630 INFO 18 --- [ main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}, MapPropertySource {name='http://gitlab.difinite.com/bombardier/config-repository.git/generic-development.properties'}, MapPropertySource {name='http://gitlab.difinite.com/bombardier/config-repository.git/be-customer-management-development.properties'}]}
2019-09-26T17:51:11.712+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:11.711 INFO 18 --- [ main] pertySourceApplicationContextInitializer : 'cloud' property source added
2019-09-26T17:51:11.712+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:11.712 INFO 18 --- [ main] nfigurationApplicationContextInitializer : Reconfiguration enabled
2019-09-26T17:51:11.727+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:11.726 INFO 18 --- [ main] c.l.u.BeCustomerManagementApplication : The following profiles are active: cloud,development
2019-09-26T17:51:16.811+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:16.810 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope : BeanFactory id=a89f4659-c9fe-3ba4-8c12-e063dff6a865
2019-09-26T17:51:17.241+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:17.241 INFO 18 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$870dc353] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-26T17:51:17.376+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:17.375 INFO 18 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1fbb8b8d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-26T17:51:17.409+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:17.408 INFO 18 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-26T17:51:17.413+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:17.412 INFO 18 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@24959ca4' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-26T17:51:17.418+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:17.417 INFO 18 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$44902e3f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-26T17:51:17.429+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:17.428 INFO 18 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-26T17:51:17.455+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:17.454 INFO 18 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a327c650] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-26T17:51:18.386+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:18.386 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8202 (http)
2019-09-26T17:51:18.642+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:18.642 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-26T17:51:18.642+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:18.642 INFO 18 --- [ main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
2019-09-26T17:51:18.680+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:18.679 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2019-09-26T17:51:18.981+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:18.981 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-26T17:51:18.982+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:18.982 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7170 ms
2019-09-26T17:51:20.495+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:20.494 INFO 18 --- [ main] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
2019-09-26T17:51:20.686+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:20.685 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Initializing ExecutorService
2019-09-26T17:51:20.689+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:20.688 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Initializing ExecutorService 'asyncExecutor'
2019-09-26T17:51:20.803+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:20.745 WARN 18 --- [ main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-09-26T17:51:20.808+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:20.807 INFO 18 --- [ main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2019-09-26T17:51:20.833+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:20.833 WARN 18 --- [ main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-09-26T17:51:20.834+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:20.833 INFO 18 --- [ main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2019-09-26T17:51:22.127+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:22.127 INFO 18 --- [ main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration :
2019-09-26T17:51:22.127+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Using generated security password: 00b3eb29-dd56-4666-8d15-f2bfbdfc0c5e
2019-09-26T17:51:22.636+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:22.636 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3c9c0d96, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5812f68b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1608bcbd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2f16c6b3, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@2766ca9d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3c7c886c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6b88ca8c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3a4621bd, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@29ca3d04, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6f63b475, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@73194df]
2019-09-26T17:51:23.594+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:23.594 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2019-09-26T17:51:23.715+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:23.712 INFO 18 --- [ main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2019-09-26T17:51:23.715+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:23.715 INFO 18 --- [ main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2019-09-26T17:51:23.752+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:23.752 INFO 18 --- [ main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1569495083746 with initial instances count: 0
2019-09-26T17:51:23.772+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:23.772 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry : Registering application BE-CUSTOMER-MANAGEMENT-TESTING with eureka with status UP
2019-09-26T17:51:23.981+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:23.981 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8202 (http) with context path ''
2019-09-26T17:51:23.982+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:23.982 INFO 18 --- [ main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8202
2019-09-26T17:51:23.986+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:23.985 INFO 18 --- [ main] c.l.u.BeCustomerManagementApplication : Started BeCustomerManagementApplication in 19.976 seconds (JVM running for 21.949)
2019-09-26T17:52:02.056+07:00 [HEALTH/0] [ERR] Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused
2019-09-26T17:52:02.056+07:00 [CELL/0] [ERR] Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.
2019-09-26T17:52:02.060+07:00 [CELL/SSHD/0] [OUT] Exit status 0
2019-09-26T17:52:02.066+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:52:02.066 INFO 18 --- [ Thread-12] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry : Unregistering application BE-CUSTOMER-MANAGEMENT-TESTING with eureka with status DOWN
2019-09-26T17:52:02.087+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:52:02.087 INFO 18 --- [ Thread-12] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Shutting down ExecutorService 'asyncExecutor'
2019-09-26T17:52:02.092+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:52:02.092 INFO 18 --- [ Thread-12] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2019-09-26T17:52:02.092+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:52:02.092 INFO 18 --- [ Thread-12] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
2019-09-26T17:52:02.516+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Exit status 143
2019-09-26T17:52:08.348+07:00 [CELL/0] [OUT] Cell e9fa9dcc-6c6e-4cd4-97cd-5781aa4c64e6 stopping instance 1f1190f4-7f86-40c3-7e68-00b0
2019-09-26T17:52:08.348+07:00 [CELL/0] [OUT] Cell e9fa9dcc-6c6e-4cd4-97cd-5781aa4c64e6 destroying container for instance 1f1190f4-7f86-40c3-7e68-00b0
2019-09-26T17:52:08.381+07:00 [API/19] [OUT] Process has crashed with type: "web"
2019-09-26T17:52:08.400+07:00 [API/19] [OUT] App instance exited with guid 80895621-4fa9-4603-bbf2-002d283e226f payload: {"instance"=>"1f1190f4-7f86-40c3-7e68-00b0", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"e9fa9dcc-6c6e-4cd4-97cd-5781aa4c64e6", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"Instance never healthy after 1m0s: Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused", "crash_count"=>3, "crash_timestamp"=>1569495128338465796, "version"=>"6e71e5bc-4ee7-428d-98ac-ec7066b22a9f"}
2019-09-26T17:52:08.540+07:00 [PROXY/0] [OUT] Exit status 137
2019-09-26T17:52:08.932+07:00 [CELL/0] [OUT] Cell e9fa9dcc-6c6e-4cd4-97cd-5781aa4c64e6 successfully destroyed container for instance 1f1190f4-7f86-40c3-7e68-00b0
2019-09-26T17:52:44.720+07:00 [API/5] [OUT] Updating process: "web"
2019-09-26T17:52:51.531+07:00 [CELL/0] [OUT] Cell ccbb6c0b-fe8a-4497-bbda-4c5b42a369bf creating container for instance 06570bc1-ee86-4397-6ff2-ed2c
```

## bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=be-customer-management-testing
spring.profiles.active=development
spring.cloud.config.uri=https://myUrlGlobalCOnfigInPivotal
spring.cloud.config.name=name1, name2
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

## application.yml

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${vcap.services.eureka-service.credentials.uri:http://localhost:8761}/eureka/
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

## application-cloud.properties

```
eureka.instance.hostname=${vcap.application.uris[0]}
eureka.instance.non-secure-port=80
eureka.instance.metadata-map.instanceId=${vcap.application.instance_id}
```

Sorry for late reply and update

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more info than that. A wild guess would be that port 8080 is the wrong port, meant just for testing, not for deployment. And by the way, it's just "Java", not JAVA in all caps (pet peeve of mine).

Comment: did you tried connecting to 8443 ? the https port

Comment: Please include the full output of running `cf push`, include the command being run and your `manifest.yml` file as well. The error is saying that the health check is failing, which likely means your app isn't starting properly or isn't listening on the correct port. The port should be read from the $PORT env variable, which the Java buildpack should do for you automatically. If you can supply the info I requested, that should help to clarify.

Comment: 'Connection refused' means nothing was listening at the target IP:port you tried to connect to.

Comment: @DanielMikusa i give more information in my question. Thanks for the help and reply. I`m appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that Tomcat is starting on the wrong port. From your logs...

```
2019-09-26T17:51:18.386+07:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-26 10:51:18.386 INFO 18 --- [ main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8202 (http)
```

It's very clearly starting on port 8202. That breaks the platform health check because the platform is asking you to start your app on port 8080. Since the app isn't listening on the requested port, the health check cannot complete successfully and Cloud Foundry must assume your app never started, so it attempts to restart the app, hoping it will work next time. Unfortunately, this is a config error so it's never going to be fixed with just a restart, so that'll loop forever.

As to why your app is starting on port 8202, it's not clear. I don't see that being set in the application.yml you specified, but it is possible that it's being set elsewhere.

For Spring Boot, you are looking for `server.port` being set. [It can be set in a number of places including application.properties, application.yml, as an env variable or system property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21083284/1585136). That needs to be set to 8080, or better yet the `$PORT` environment variable which is set by Cloud Foundry and contains the expected port on which your app should listen. (Side note, the Java buildpack should configure this for you unless you are overriding the start command or doing something to alter it's default behavior).

You'll know it's right when Tomcat reports that it has started on port 8080 and the health check passes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for your help and it works. Sorry for late response

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, then I realized that the property `server.port=8083` was accidentally propagating into the deployed environment. I ensured that this property was only set when running on my local machine and my issue resolved.