# Can anyone help me change port number of server using spring boot CLI & Groovy

Tags: spring-boot

**Hello.groovy file: -**

```
@RestController
class ThisWillActuallyRun {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        "Hello World!"
    } 

}
```

[image: This is the output in Command Prompt which shows application failed to start]

Comment: Welcome Mit. Could you please copy the error message and post it, instead of uploading an image of it? Makes it easier to copy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure port for a Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/how-to-configure-port-for-a-spring-boot-application)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have already some server running on that port (8080).

Or configure an another port in

`src/main/resources/application.properties`
Add this:

```
server.port=8073
```