# Spring Boot application shutting down immediately

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Why spring boot application is shutting down automatically.

Message that is showing in console.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-06-03 23:25:43.794  INFO 26936 --- [           main] c.e.d.DatajpaexampleApplication          : Starting DatajpaexampleApplication on HMECL002810A with PID 26936 (C:\Users\Ravishankar.kumar\Desktop\MyWorkspace\SpringDataJpa\datajpaexample\target\classes started by Ravishankar.kumar in C:\Users\Ravishankar.kumar\Desktop\MyWorkspace\SpringDataJpa\datajpaexample)
2020-06-03 23:25:43.797  INFO 26936 --- [           main] c.e.d.DatajpaexampleApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-03 23:25:44.467  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-06-03 23:25:44.515  INFO 26936 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 27ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-06-03 23:25:45.148  INFO 26936 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-03 23:25:45.161  INFO 26936 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-06-03 23:25:46.299  INFO 26936 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-06-03 23:25:46.358  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-06-03 23:25:46.495  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-06-03 23:25:46.571  INFO 26936 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-06-03 23:25:46.571  INFO 26936 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-06-03 23:25:46.583  INFO 26936 --- [           main] c.e.d.DatajpaexampleApplication          : Started DatajpaexampleApplication in 3.261 seconds (JVM running for 3.692)
2020-06-03 23:25:46.787  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-06-03 23:25:47.041  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2020-06-03 23:25:47.351  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-06-03 23:25:47.360  INFO 26936 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-03 23:26:47.396  INFO 26936 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-03 23:26:47.410  INFO 26936 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-03 23:26:47.411  INFO 26936 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-06-03 23:26:47.419  INFO 26936 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>datajpaexample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>datajpaexample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_datajpa
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

server.port = 8085
```

DatajpaexampleApplication.class

```
package com.example.datajpaexample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DatajpaexampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DatajpaexampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I tried multiple things, but same problem.

1. i deleted *C:\Users\classpath.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.32*
2. Added these extra dependencies

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
     <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Could anyone help me out.

Comment: it should be part of application.properties file check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21083284/2704032

Comment: but that port also not running and after sometime automatically shutting down.

Comment: are you using docker? if yes, check the entrypoint

Comment: NO. i am not using entrypoint

Comment: could you see in console and print the stacktrace here

Comment: now i added that console log also.

Comment: And it should keep running because? I suspect you set a property indicating it is a web based application to `false` either in your `main`  method or in your `application.properties`. Then there is nothing left and it will directly shutdown. Adding more dependencies won't help. Fix your config or bootstrap code.

Comment: i added application.properties and main method also... could you please look on that code also..

Comment: I think you miss `driverClassName` in application.properties, And the driver dependency (MySQL Connector)

Answer (score 0):

I changed parent version *2.3.0.RELEASE* to *2.2.1.RELEASE*. Now working fine.

Comment: but this is not correct solution. You do not change your springboot versions like this. Each version has different features in it.

Comment: ya correct. but i tried multiple way to resolve that issue in previous version, but not resolved. if you have any suggestion on that previous version , please give me, i will check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the code `<scope>provided</scope>` for the artifactId `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and rerun the application

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem my application. how to fix this problems, ı will say to you.

you must change "spring-starter-test" in application.properties, then save with ctrl+s(You can use maven repository for this).

Old version spring starter web have a vulnerabilitiy, therefore intellij shutting your application