# How to expose ${PORT} spring boot application random port in docker?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, port

How to expose `${PORT}` spring boot application in `docker`?

Spring boot application starts on a random port and I have to expose the same in docker.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can "fix" spring port, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/how-to-configure-port-for-a-spring-boot-application

Comment: I used the same in my `properties` file. Now I want to expose it to docker.

Comment: Check the docker "run" command argument, you can expose port with argument `-p <host port>:<container port>`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, better to have a static port on the application side otherwise mapping exact port will be hard.

[How to configure port for a Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/how-to-configure-port-for-a-spring-boot-application)

Another option is to use the **host network**, so you will be able to access the application using container port, but this option is available for Linux only.

> If you use the **host network mode** for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not get its own IP-address allocated. **For instance, if you run a container which binds to port 80 and you use host networking,** **the container’s application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address**.

[docker-host-network](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

```
docker run -it --net host --rm my_app
```

**suppose your app is running on some random port `8087`, then you will able to access the application using http://localhost:8087 because of `--net host`**