# Is there a way to specify port number running Uber/Fat JARs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm being able to run a Spring Web Application on browsers by executing an Uber/Fat JAR using `java -jar JAR-file` command but I don't know whether I can specify the port number to run on like in Angular using `--port`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure port for a Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/how-to-configure-port-for-a-spring-boot-application)

Answer (score 1):

you can use *server.port* property in command line to specify the port number.

```
java -jar JAR-file --server.port=8083
```

or

```
java -jar -Dserver.port=8083 JAR-file
```